# jspdf download button doesn't do anything when clicked. in android cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, pdf

i make an android app with cordova and angularjs. I have made download pdf button and it works fine on my laptop. but when compiled to android, my button doesn't do anything when clicked. i have added plugin `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`

i followed tutorial here http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/01/08/generating-pdf-inside-of-phonegap-apps/ and here my code.

```
           $scope.exportPDF = function(){       
                    alert("tes");
                    //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
                    console.log("generating pdf...");
                    var doc = new jsPDF();

                    doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

                    doc.setFont("courier");
                    doc.setFontType("normal");
                    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
                    doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

                    var pdfOutput = doc.output();
                    console.log( pdfOutput );

                    //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
                    console.log("file system...");
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

                       console.log(fileSystem.name);
                       console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
                       console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

                       fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
                          var fileEntry = entry;
                          console.log(entry);

                          entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                             writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                             console.log("write success");
                          };

                          console.log("writing to file");
                             writer.write( pdfOutput );
                          }, function(error) {
                             console.log(error);
                          });

                       }, function(error){
                          console.log(error);
                       });
                    },
                    function(event){
                     console.log( evt.target.error.code );
                    });
}
```

the alert is worked, but my pdf still not work. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

1. Use your code to generate pdf and store it locally or even better do it server side
2. Install In-App browser plugin

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
   ```
3. Create a download button with

   ```
   onclick="window.open("LOCAL_OR_REMOTE_URL", '_system');
   ```

Not only will this download the pdf it will open the pdf in the browser/pdf app

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open(PDF_URL, '_system')">
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF
</button>
```

Comment: this button for generate my pdf `<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="exportPDF()"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF</button>` can you give the example code? where should i put the `onclick` like your code?

Comment: i can't generate my pdf with exportPDF function. i don't know what's the problem. so i don't know about PDF_URL in your code, because i can't generate my pdf to local.

Comment: can't you do it server side

Comment: i tried it with inAppBrowser, when i click the button, it shows error like this.

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/[object%20Window)

Comment: as you can see issue is in the [object%20Window.. part. its not getting the proper name  instead some JS type

Comment: i have my pdf url like this `data:application/pdf;base64,blabla...` but the window.open cannot open it. what should i do? thanks in advance.

Comment: data-url may not work as no app can listen to the intent. Intent works like 'if url ends with .pdf or if it's a pdf file i(app) wish to open it'  But with data-url it may be difficult

Comment: why don't u generate the pdf on server side or save this blog to a file and try to open it

Comment: i have make it on server side. and now i have a bug. when pdf file appears, and I want to return to my app. the back button must be pressed twice. if once, it will remain in the chrome and the address bar displays the domain link. example

my pdf url : `http://1.1.1.1/folder/controller/pdf`
when back pressed once : `http://1.1.1.1/`

how do i fix it?